# How to determine the filename of the executing function

Tags: powershell

I am running some code and trying to log specific things.  In the log, I would like to record the current function and the filename where that function exists.

For instance my "Main.ps1" file looks similar to the following:

```
. .\UtilityFunctions.ps1

function Main-Routine
{
    utility-method
}

Main-Routine
```

My UtilityFunctions.ps1 looks similar to the following:

```
function utility-method
{
    "{0}.{1}" -f $MyInvocation.ScriptName, $MyInvocation.MyCommand
}
```

This prints to the console as follows:

*mypath*\Main.ps1.utility-method

I want it to print this instead:

*mypath*\UtilityFunctions.ps1.utility-method

It seems calling $MyInvocation always returns the filename that is invoked at startup, rather than the filename where the function exists.  How do I get the filename which contains my function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is stored in object returned by `Get-Command`

```
(Get-Command Utility-Method).ScriptBlock.File
```

It should work both for functions defined in dot-sourced scripts, as functions in modules.

Comment: perfect, thanks.  I modified as follows so it is generic:  (Get-Command $MyInvocation.MyCommand).ScriptBlock.File